# Camel, JAXB into ActiveMQ creating XML automatically

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, apache-camel, activemq-classic

I have a Camel route set up as follows:

```
  <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route>
        <from uri="file://C:/incoming?noop=true"/>
        <log message="File Recieved"/>
        <unmarshal>
            <jaxb contextPath="org.ben.camel.spareparts.model" ignoreJAXBElement="true"/>
        </unmarshal>
        <log message="Store: ${body.getStore}"/>
        <choice>
            <when>
                <simple>${body.getStore} == 2</simple>
                <log message="New Item from Store 2"/>
                <bean ref="processor" beanType="org.ben.camel.spareparts.model.StockReportProcessor"/>
                <split>
                    <simple>${body}</simple>
                    <log message="item split!"/>
                    <marshal>
                        <jaxb contextPath="org.ben.camel.spareparts.model" ignoreJAXBElement="false"/>
                    </marshal>
                    <to uri="activemq:queue:store2"/>
                </split>
            </when>
            <when>
                <simple>${body.getStore} == 1</simple>
                <log message="New Item from Store 1"/>
                <bean ref="processor" beanType="org.ben.camel.spareparts.model.StockReportProcessor"/>
            </when>
        </choice>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

It takes a XML object, splits it by  XML elements, and adds the elements to a queue. I'm unmarshalling into a POJO to extract just the  element list, which then goes into the split component.

My problem is that I can't seem to get the POJO into ActiveMQ without being XML. Even if I try marshalling it into a POJO again before submitting, it still arrives in the MQ as XML. I'm wondering, if I have JAXB annotations on an object which gets put into ActiveMQ, does it automatically convert to XML? If so, how do I stop this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First marshal just turn the jaxb object into xml input stream.

```
<marshal>
     <jaxb contextPath="org.ben.camel.spareparts.model" ignoreJAXBElement="false"/>
  </marshal>
```

Second, camel can tell the message type by looking up the body instance.

```
protected JmsMessageType getJMSMessageTypeForBody(Exchange exchange, Object body, Map<String, Object> headers, Session session, CamelContext context) {
    JmsMessageType type = null;
    // let body determine the type
    if (body instanceof Node || body instanceof String) {
        type = Text;
    } else if (body instanceof byte[] || body instanceof WrappedFile || body instanceof File || body instanceof Reader
            || body instanceof InputStream || body instanceof ByteBuffer || body instanceof StreamCache) {
        type = Bytes;
    } else if (body instanceof Map) {
        type = Map;
    } else if (body instanceof Serializable) {
        type = Object;            
    } else if (exchange.getContext().getTypeConverter().tryConvertTo(File.class, body) != null
            || exchange.getContext().getTypeConverter().tryConvertTo(InputStream.class, body) != null) {
        type = Bytes;
    }
    return type;
}
```

If you want to send the Object message to the ActiveMQ, you need to make sure the message body is instance of Serializable, otherwise camel will turn it into a input stream with the help of JAXB fallback converter even you umarshall the xml into Java object.